# Reboot a Ubuntu server based on AWS Cloudwatch Metric

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I'm in the process of debugging a random spike on a server and in the mean time I would love to be able to just reboot the machine when a certain CPU threshold is met.

The AWS Cloudwatch rule is set up and works beautifully to notify me by email.  What I would prefer is to have it take action and just cycle the machine.

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Cloudwatch](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/12/amazon-cloudwatch-alarms.html) can send alarms not only through email but through HTTP(S) or Amazon SQS. You could create a script to receive these notification on your EC2 instance or on an external monitoring server and execute server reboot through `ssh shudown -r` or through [EC2 API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/index.html?ApiReference-cmd-RebootInstances.html).